# Results in reverse order with Cassandra

Tags: php, cassandra

I have a column family where column names are timestamps. I need to retrieve a certain number of columns using ascending order. How can i achieve this?

I'm actually using PHP and the Cassandra php client library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, used

```
$data = $this->cassandra->cf("UserNotifications")->get(Cassandra::escape($username), null, null, null, true);
```

Instead of

```
$data = $this->cassandra->get(...);
```

The first way operates at lower level and thanks to the fifth parameter I can reverse the order of the data returned.

Comment: You can do that using CQL like "SELECT FIRST 10 REVERSED 'b'..'a' FROM Test_CF WHERE KEY = 'dfdsf';" and try executing it via phpcassa or Cassandra PHP PDO